# When I opened my iOS app, the screen turns black. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I'm making iOS apps. I'm a total novice developer.

I want everyone to use my app so I choose iOS 10.0 in Target Info on Xcode. Now my app can be downloaded on the App store. However when I opened my app on iPad (iOS 12.4.6), the screen turned black and I can do nothing.

Do you come up with any problems?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough info to help you out here - are you working from a basic tutorial to help you make sure you can get your view displayed at startup? This sounds like it isn't related to the iOS 10 target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you coded your app programmatically but in your app delegate, check for the `var window: UIWindow?`. I had the same issue when I forgot to put the "?" after "UIWindow". Hope that helps.

Comment: Hope you find the bug!

Comment: I checked my AppDelegate, but I could not find "var window: UIWindow?" on AppDelegate. However, I realized SceneDelegate (which is available on 13.0? ) is added. I think SceneDelegate is the problem. I found "var window: UIWindow?" on SceneDelegate and "?"is also written.

I added "var window: UIWindow?" on AppDelegate, my app worked well. 

Thank you so much:)

Comment: That's great! Glad it worked! If you can upvote my answer, that would insure that others can also try my suggestion Much appreciated! Happy coding!